# How to add/subtract row values from each other in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
    credit  debit
0   0.0     89.40
1   0.0     4.33
2   0.0     12.00
3   500.0   0.00
4   0.0     5.40
```

If I know the current balance is 300, how do I make a **balance column** that subtracts the debit from each row and adds the credit from each row?

I have tried using `df.sub` but I am having no luck...

The Balance column should look like:

```
balance
300.00
389.40
393.33
405.33
-94.27
```

here is the code for the sample DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'credit': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 500.0, 4: 0.0},'debit': {0: 89.4, 1: 4.33, 2: 12.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 5.4}})
```

Comment: `df['balance'] = 300 - df['debit'] + df['credit']`

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the effort but please look at the edited post to see what the balance column should look like. I hope that clarifies things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking that you are looking for a "running balance" of the dataframe. If yes, continue to read else discard.

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import accumulate
import operator
import numpy as np

DF = pd.DataFrame({'credit': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 500.0, 4: 0.0},
 'debit': {0: 89.4, 1: 4.33, 2: 12.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 5.4}})

Initial_Balance = 300
Running_Balance = np.array(list(accumulate(DF.debit-DF.credit, func=operator.add)))+Initial_Balance
DF["Running_Balance"] = Running_Balance
print(DF)
```

This gives the following output.

```py
   credit  debit  Running_Balance
0     0.0  89.40           389.40
1     0.0   4.33           393.73
2     0.0  12.00           405.73
3   500.0   0.00           -94.27
4     0.0   5.40           -88.87
```

Comment: Thank you, this is it

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
In [511]: df['balance'] = df.debit.cumsum() + 300 - df.credit.cumsum()

In [512]: df
Out[512]: 
   credit  debit  balance
0     0.0  89.40   389.40
1     0.0   4.33   393.73
2     0.0  12.00   405.73
3   500.0   0.00   -94.27
4     0.0   5.40   -88.87
```

OR:

```
In [513]: df['balance'] = df.debit.cumsum().sub(df.credit.cumsum()).add(300)
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the effort but please look at the edited post to see what the balance column should look like. I hope that clarifies things

Comment: What is the logic for creating this `balance` column?

Comment: its like a bank statement, a credit is an inflow of cash and a debit is an outflow. I know the current balance of the account ($300) but I am trying fill in what the historical balance was after each transaction in the dataframe

Comment: @zarkmuckerberg Please check the `EDIT` part of my answer. Let me know if this is what you want?